# Add counter to view with rendered entity output

Tags: 7, views

On my site I've a search based on Views, with an exposed filter. The style output is "rendered entity", and I've to add the "result counter" beside the title.

Is there a way to do this or I've to use "fields" output?

I should have something like:

> 1. Title1
> 2. Title2

Comment: Duplicate of already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973975/drupal-return-number-of-results-in-a-view

Comment: And, I don't want a "total rows" number, but a row counter (I edit the message)

Answer (score 1):

Result number is a views field node has no clue about. You need to use "fields" output to add fields that are not in the node itself - that's the very reason of this output's existence.